# v-menu with v-text-field activator - Open menu when input and close only when focus out

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-menu with v-text-field activator. Currently v-menu will close on focus out or when we click inside textbox again.
Requirement is to open v-menu on input/focus and keep it open until focus out and Close it on focus out.

Please find the code pan link for the same issue
[Codepan](https://codepen.io/pen?template=GRXPWam)

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="app-template">
  <v-app>
    <div class="d-flex justify-space-around">
  
      <v-text-field id = "menu-activator"
        label="Password"
      type="input" v-model="input"
      >
       
      </v-text-field>
  
      <v-menu activator="#menu-activator">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            :value="index"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title + ' ' + input }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</script>

<div id="app"></div>
<div id="app"></div>

const { createApp } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;

const vuetify = createVuetify();

const app = createApp({
  template: "#app-template",
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: "Order#" },
      { title: "Unit#" },
      { title: "Bol#" },
      { title: "PO#" }
    ],
    input: ""
  })
})
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount("#app");
```

Tried using a v-model on v-menu and setting that v-model as true on input/click of text field and false on blur. That works but a new issue with this is emit function is not triggering when we select(click) any menu option (v-list-item)

Comment: "emit function is not triggering when we select(click) any menu option (v-list-item)" ...What emit are you referring to?